# add character before first word in line

Tags: regex, vim

I want to add a minus sign "-" infront of the first word in a line on the editor VIM. The lines contains spaces for indentation. The indentation shall not be touched. E.g

#### As Is

```
  list point 1
      sub list point 2
  and so on...
```

#### I want

```
  - list point 1
      - sub list point 2
  - and so on...
```

I can find the first word, but i struggle with replacing it in the correct way.

```
^\s*\w
```

in Vim

```
/^\s*\w
```

But in the replacement I always remove the complete found part....

```
:s/^\s*\w/- \w/
```

Which leads to

```
- ist point 1
- ub list point 2
- nd so on...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&` which is replaced with the matched string:

```
:%s/\w/- &
```

Comment: worked. I have to wait until I can accept the answer.... nearly. Interesstingly the \w seems to have problems with german umlauts, like ü,ä,ö. Then you get somthing like that `   Ü- berholen`

Comment: Nice one. Didn't knew that

Comment: You could try \k then for "keyword", or \S for all non-whitespace.

Comment: This works, by the way, because substitutes always act on the FIRST match in a line.

Comment: @Ben, `/g` is omitted exactly for that reason. (not to replace globally)

Comment: Yes, that was my point. The question was explicitly looking for the first word on the line using `^\s*` which you show is probably not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party but:

```
:%norm! I- <CR>
```

And another one with `:s`:

```
:%s/^\s*/&- /
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `falsetrue`'s answer: You can capture the first word character and print it out along with the leading `-`:

```
%s/\(\w\)/- \1/
```

Answer (score 1):

:normal cmd may help too:

```
:%norm! wi-
```

note that after `-` there is a  space.

Comment: You can forgo the `wi` for just `I`